# Freezes and browser crashes when using Linux

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, freeze, crash

With any Distro Installed to my PC, I get the following ACPI errors (`ACPI Error: Aborting Method`) while booting up:
[image]

Also while using my pc it randomly freezes and the only way is to power it off directly, other errors are like browser's crash

My PC Specs are :

Asus ROG Strix B450F

AMD Ryzen 5

GSKILL TRIDENT

WD SSD

SEAGATE HDD

GTX 1050TI

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure these errors have nothing to do with your freezes. Please expand on *"randomly freezes"* - when does it happen, how often does it happen (daily? a few times every hour? Every minute?), does it happen when you're doing something specific, does the power off button work, how much RAM you have, everything. What's *"browsers crash"*?

Comment: Buggy bios ? (BIOS providing wrong memory map for the tmp devices) Check if update available. You could also try disabling ACPI (add  acpi=off to the boot command line) ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSES since you should not really run your system like that)

Comment: It happens pretty frequently, like withing 10 mins of boot up and sometimes it doesn't happen at all, Specifically when I am using any browser I  guess or when its open in background, RAM: 16 GB,(Just mentioning : I didn't allocate any swap). I haven't tried the power button but the restart button works. Browser Crash : Not specific browsers, but all shows a crash message like "Something went wrong" and all the tabs closes

Comment: Make sure you've got NVIDIA proprietary drivers installed - this depends on your distro. The open source `nouveau` driver which comes by default is known to be *very unstable* with new NVIDIA architectures. Google for "NVIDIA drivers your_distro". If it's Ubuntu, https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Please [edit] your question so all relevant information is in the question (no need for "EDIT: ", just edit and write it as though it had been there from the beginning). Comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning so all details need to be in the question.